# Approximate $e^{1/3}$ within $ 10^{-8}$ using Taylor's inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to use Taylor's inequality to determine how many terms required to approximate $e^{1/3}$ within $ 10^{-8}$

Here's what I tried:
$$
f(x)=e^x
$$
$$
||f^{n+1}(x)||=||e^x||
$$
$$
||e^x||=e^{1/3}\le3
$$
$$
\frac{||f^{n+1}(x)||}{(n+1)!}d^{n+1}\le10^{-8}
$$
$$
\frac{3}{(n+1)!}1^{n+1}\le10^{-8}
$$
$$
3x10^8\le(n+1)!
$$
$$
12!\le(n+1)!
$$
$$
n=11
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't mean the $(n+1)$-st power of the function $f$ throughout your solution. The derivative notation is $f^{(n+1)}$, not $f^{n+1}$ which means an exponent.

Answer (score 1):

$e^x = 1 + x + \frac 12 x^2 + \cdots  \frac 1{n!}x^n + \epsilon$

$\epsilon = {\frac {f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}}x^{n}$

OP has suggested using 3 as the upper bound if $f^{(n+1)}(c)$  It is probably a little bit larger than we need, but why not.

$\epsilon < \frac {1}{(n+1)!}(\frac 13)^{(n+1)} (3)$

What is the smallest $n$ such that
$\epsilon < \frac {1}{(n+1)!}(\frac 13)^n<10^{-8} $

$\frac {1}{(8)!}(\frac 13)^7<1.13\times 10^{-8} $

Comment: "The error is always less than the last term added"??? Yes, for series satisfying the alternating series test (a.k.a. Leibniz series), but that's not true in general.

Comment: @zipirovich you are correct, I took a short-cut, that was too short.

Comment: This looks a whole lot better now!

Answer (score 0):

I think you did some things a bit sloppily. We have the Lagrange remainder

$$|f(x)-T_n(x_0,x)|=\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(\xi_n)|}{(n+1)!} |x-x_0|^{n+1}$$

where $\xi_n$ is unknown; all that we know is that it is between $x_0$ and $x$. You take $x_0=0,x=1/3$, and then you're left to estimate that derivative. You can bound that derivative by $e^{1/3}$, which you can in turn bound by $e$, and in turn by $3$. That gives an overall bound of $\frac{3^{-n}}{(n+1)!}$. After that, you probably want to just identify an appropriate $n$ by guess-and-check.